# Magento admin showing multiple icons on buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml

I see multiple icons on all admin buttons, please have a look at the screenshot below

[image: multiple icons in Magento admin]

And I see that Magento is spitting two extra span tags while it should wrap the button text in single span tag but for some reason, it wraps two more `span` tags. I have flushed Magento cache, cleared out contents of `cache` directory but all in vain. It's a weird behavior and I never encountered such issue before while working with Magento before.

Can anybody give me a clue?

Note: No JS error is there in the console. And, no relevant error found in Magento logs. Magento version is `1.9.3.9`

Answer (score 0):

The various icons appear to be a CSS issue, as each of these spans has the `button.back span` rule which apply the background. Actually, 3 `span` tags are not common, but here also have 3, but without the problem of the icons, because my CSS has these rules that I did not see in the image you uploaded:

`button span span {
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    display: inline !important;
}`

Comment: this is not a CSS issue, the real issue is those extra spans, I confirmed in other Magento instance of same version there is only one span tag. Of course a quick workaround would be to change CSS but we need to address the issue that spits out those two extra tags.